# literal constant vs variable in math library

Tags: c, linker

So, I know that in `C` you need to link the code to the math library, `libm`, to be able to use its functions. Today, while I was trying to demonstrate this to a friend, and explain why you need to do this, I came across the following situation that I do not understand.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* #define VARIABLE */

int main(void)
{
#ifdef VARIABLE
    double a = 2.0;
    double b = sqrt(a);
    printf("b = %lf\n",b);
#else
    double b = sqrt(2.0);
    printf("b = %lf\n",b);
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

If `VARIABLE` is defined, you need to link against `libm` as you would normally expect; otherwise you get the usual `main.c:(.text+0x29): undefined reference to sqrt` linking error indicating that the compiler cannot find the definition for the function `sqrt`. I was surprised to see that if I comment `#define VARIABLE`, the code runs fine and the result is correct!

Why is it that I need to link to `libm` when variables are used but I don't need to do so when literal constants are used? How does the compiler find the definition of `sqrt` when the library is not linked? I'm using `gcc 4.4.5` under linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As everyone mentions, yes it has to do with [constant folding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding).

**With optimizations off**, GCC only seems to do it when `sqrt(2.0)` is used. Here's the evidence:

**Case 1:** With the variable.

```
    .file   "main.c"
    .section    .rodata
.LC1:
    .string "b = %lf\n"
    .text
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $32, %esp
    fldl    .LC0
    fstpl   24(%esp)
    fldl    24(%esp)
    fsqrt
    fucom   %st(0)
    fnstsw  %ax
    sahf
    jp  .L5
    je  .L2
    fstp    %st(0)
    jmp .L4
.L5:
    fstp    %st(0)
.L4:
    fldl    24(%esp)
    fstpl   (%esp)
    call    sqrt
.L2:
    fstpl   16(%esp)
    movl    $.LC1, %eax
    fldl    16(%esp)
    fstpl   4(%esp)
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    printf
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
    .size   main, .-main
    .section    .rodata
    .align 8
.LC0:
    .long   0
    .long   1073741824
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

You can see that it emits a call to the `sqrt` function. So you'll get a linker error if you don't link the math library.

**Case 2:** With the Literal.

```
    .file   "main.c"
    .section    .rodata
.LC1:
    .string "b = %lf\n"
    .text
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $32, %esp
    fldl    .LC0
    fstpl   24(%esp)
    movl    $.LC1, %eax
    fldl    24(%esp)
    fstpl   4(%esp)
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    printf
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
    .size   main, .-main
    .section    .rodata
    .align 8
.LC0:
    .long   1719614413
    .long   1073127582
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

There's no call to `sqrt`. Hence no linker error.

---

**With optimizations on**, GCC will do constant propagation in both cases. So no linker error in either case.

```
$ gcc main.c -save-temps
main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `sqrt'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
$ gcc main.c -save-temps -O2
$
```

Answer (score 5):

GCC can do [constant folding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding) for several standard-library functions.  Obviously, if the function is folded at compile-time, there is no need for a run-time function call, so no need to link to libm.  You could confirm this by taking a looking at the assembler that the compiler produces (using `objdump` or similar).

I guess these optimizations are only triggered when the argument is a constant expression.

Comment: "only triggered when the argument is a constant expression" - I believe that if you compile with `-O2`, the version with `VARIABLE` defined will no longer call the runtime `sqrt()` function (and won't need to be linked to `libm`).  Also, just so readers don't get the idea that this is something only done by GCC, this kind of optimization is generally done by any C/C++ compiler.

Answer (score 4):

I think it GCC uses its builtin. I compiled your code with: `-fno-builtin-sqrt` and got the expected linker error.

> The ISO C90 functions ... `sin`, `sprintf`, `sqrt` ... are all
>   recognized as built-in functions unless `-fno-builtin` is specified

Comment: huh! that actually does lead to link error in the case of constants! Is this only for `sqrt` or includes other functions as well? [EDIT] Thanks for update

Answer (score 2):

That's because `gcc` is clever enough to figure out that the square root of the constant 2 is *also* a constant, so it just generates code like:

```
mov register, whatever-the-square-root-of-2-is
```

Hence no need to do a square root calculation at run time, `gcc` has already done it at compile time.

This is akin to a benchmarking program which does bucketloads of calculations then does nothing with the result:

```
int main (void) {
    // do something rather strenuous
    return 0;
}
```

You're likely (at high optimisation levels) to see all the `do something rather strenuous` code optimised out of existence.

The `gcc` docs have a whole page dedicated to these built-ins [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#Other-Builtins) and the relevant section in that page for `sqrt` and others is:

> The ISO C90 functions `abort, abs, acos, asin, atan2, atan, calloc, ceil, cosh, cos, exit, exp, fabs, floor, fmod, fprintf, fputs, frexp, fscanf, isalnum, isalpha, iscntrl, isdigit, isgraph, islower, isprint, ispunct, isspace, isupper, isxdigit, tolower, toupper, labs, ldexp, log10, log, malloc, memchr, memcmp, memcpy, memset, modf, pow, printf, putchar, puts, scanf, sinh, sin, snprintf, sprintf, sqrt, sscanf, strcat, strchr, strcmp, strcpy, strcspn, strlen, strncat, strncmp, strncpy, strpbrk, strrchr, strspn, strstr, tanh, tan, vfprintf, vprintf` and `vsprintf` are all recognized as built-in functions unless `-fno-builtin` is specified (or `-fno-builtin-function` is specified for an individual function).

So, quite a lot, really :-)