# Undefined reference to `pow' when the exponent is changed?

Tags: c

I'm having some strange issues with `pow()`. If i do

`return 44330*(1 - pow((float) pressure / PRESSURE0, 1/5.255F));`

where `pressure` is an `int32_t` and `PRESSURE0`is a constant, I get an error saying undefined reference to `pow'. However, if I do

`return 44330*(1 - pow((float) pressure / PRESSURE0, 1.0F));`

it's fine. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Please try -lm in your compiler options.

Comment: This is most likely caused by a compiler optimization: in the second case, since the exponent is `1.0`, there is no need to call the `pow()` function. To fix the first variant, try linking with `-lm`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920789/literal-constant-vs-variable-in-math-library and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049412/do-math-functions-of-constant-expressions-get-pre-calculated-at-compile-time

Comment: I don't think this -lm will solve this - his second example works and I assume it compiles the same. @Kate - are you using a c++ compiler? Can you provide your make file and headers you use for pow?

Comment: @IshayPeled Reproduce it. You will see exactly the issue OP has. See my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, in order to use math functions like `sqrt()`, `pow()` etc. you need to link with the math library, `libm` (on gcc, use the `-lm` option).

However, the compiler is free to apply optimizations, especially when the arguments to the functions are constants. Consider the following two simplified functions:

```
double f1(int pressure) {
   return pow((float) pressure / PRESSURE0, 1/5.255F);
}

double f2(int pressure) {
   return pow((float) pressure / PRESSURE0, 1.0F);
}
```

This gets compiled into i386 code as follows (unnecessary assembler directives removed):

```
f1:
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        subl    $24, %esp

; (float) pressure / PRESSURE0
        fildl   8(%ebp)
        fldl    .LC0
        fdivrp  %st, %st(1)

; pow()
        fldl    .LC1
        fstpl   8(%esp)
        fstpl   (%esp)
        call    pow

        leave
        ret
```

```
f2:
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp

; (float) pressure / PRESSURE0
        fildl   8(%ebp)
        fldl    .LC0
        fdivrp  %st, %st(1)

; NO call to pow(x, 1.0), since it would not change the value of x

        popl    %ebp
        ret
```

In `f2()`, since the exponent to `pow()` is `1.0`, there is no need to call the `pow()` function - the compiler detects this and removes the function call.
Hence, if there are no other calls to any math functions in your code, it is not necessary to link against `libm` in that particular case.

See also

- [literal constant vs variable in math library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920789/literal-constant-vs-variable-in-math-library)
- [Do math functions of constant expressions get pre-calculated at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049412/do-math-functions-of-constant-expressions-get-pre-calculated-at-compile-time)

Comment: Side note: this is why undefined reference to function is treated by the standard as *undefined behaviour, no diagnostic required*: so that compilers can optimize without having to keep a paper trail of what they optimized out